# Concatenacion de variables en cadenas, python

Tags: python

-Por lo visto hay numerosas maneras de concatenar variables en cadenas. Sin embargo, mi atencion quedo fijada en la siguiente...

```
variable = 9;
cadena = "La variable es igual a ==> ",variable;
```

-Bien es cierto que, al hacer esto, realmente no se estaria creando una cadena sino una tupla. Ahora la pregunta es:
Por que, al pasarle como parametro esa tupla (sin llegar a pasar por la variable 'cadena') a la funcion print() este lo imprime por pantalla cual si fuese una cadena...

```
variable = 9;
print('La variable es igual a ==> ',variable);
```

La salida de esto es...

```
La variable es igual a ==>  9
```

Mas sin embargo, al pasarle la variable 'cadena' a print(), este lo imprime cual si fuera una tupla, como deberia de ser...

```
variable = 9;
cadena = "La variable es igual a ==> ",variable;
print(cadena);
```

La salida de esto es...

```
("La variable cadena es", 9)
```

No se supone que las variables son al fin y al cabo medios de almacenamiento temporal de informacion? por que entonces hay una reaccion diferente ante exactamente la misma informacion.

Comment: Bueno, en realidad **no** estás creando una string en la primera forma. Estás creando una tupla.

Comment: sencillamente porque en unos casos estas pasando a travez de una funcion que da formato, y en el primer caso, solo estas agarrando la cadena como viene... si quisieras darle formato, alguna funcion tendria que hacerlo no?

Comment: Por cierto (y esto ya no tiene que ver con lo que preguntas) los semicolons ( ; ) son innecesarios en Python.

Comment: @revliscano si, lo se, los utilizo por que estoy acostumbrado a lenguajes en los que se utilizan y no quiero perder la costubre...

Comment: Te faltó la forma: `cadena = 'La variable es igual a ==> ' + str(variable)`

Comment: @Benito-B asi esta mejor?

Comment: Esto no tiene ninguna lógica, debería salir un error al intentar concatenar una cadena con un número.

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos no , en ese caso se crea una tupla no una cadena, por ende no hay error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

- Estas viendo dos formas diferentes de interpolación en Python ahí en las dos ultimas, una es el formato de cadena f, y la otra usa el método format
- No se te permite modificar en lo absoluto la tupla (en el primero no estás interpolando como en las dos siguientes, más bien estás haciendo una tupla)

Te añado más dudas, prueba esto (la forma con la que aprendí a interpolar cuando empecé):

```
cadena = "ipsum"
numerito = 666
print("lorem %s %s" % (cadena, numerito))
```

Comment: Recomiendo visitar la documentación de Python sobre métodos y métodos de interpolación

Comment: Por favor pasame el link, al buscar 'metodos de interpolacion' solo me aparecen funciones relacionadas con numpy, cosas que no tienen nada que ver...